# How can I use mirror lockup with wireless remote on a Canon T4i?

Tags: remote, canon-650d, mirror-lockup

I'm using a Canon T4i. When mirror lockup is enabled, if I press the button on the wireless remote, I have the impression that mirror lockup is not performed. Am I doing something wrong? According to the instruction manual, the only thing to do would be setting the shooting mode to timer, in which case the camera either should wait for 2 seconds (when pressing the dslr shooting button), or should shoot if the remote is used.

Comment: Not that this is very helpful but while using the 2-second delay on my remote shutter release, i found that the mirror did in fact lock-up i just missed it. Previously i had thought my mirror would not lock either, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Once you enable the mirror lockup in the custom functions, it should wait for 2 seconds even if you use the remote. See the Manual:

> With Remote Controller RC-6 (sold separately) set to a 2-sec. delay, press the transmit button and the mirror will lockup before the picture is taken 2 sec. later.

If it shoots immediately, you need to set it to the 2-sec delay instead of the immediate shooting with remote. Otherwise the camera does not have time to stop vibrating after the mirror locked up. You should be able to hear the mirror lock up when you press the remote button and then again hear it expose (and unlock the mirror) once it takes the picture 2 seconds later.

Comment: I have an RC-6. If I set to 2-sec delay, the remote does not work. As per instruction manual, only the "10sec/remote" option can be used and I really don't think the mirror is brought up before shooting.

Comment: If you test it with 10 seconds, you can find out if the mirror locks up by looking into the viewfinder. If you can see out through the lens, it does not lock up. Also: Are you sure you activated the mirror lockup in the custom functions?

Comment: yes, I enabled the feature. the remote can only be used when selecting the option "timer/remote" and I don't think the RC-6 locks up the mirror when I press the button. If I press the button on the DSLR, the mirror does lock up.

Comment: If you keep the camera in front of you when you press the remote button, you should see if the mirror locks up. There should be no room for "I think / do not think so".

Comment: why would the dslr take the photo immediately then? it would wait for 2 sec don't you think?

Comment: Ok now I get it. The remote does not work with the 2sec delay setting, but it works with the normal no-delay remote control setting. In that case, something is broken, I would take remote and camera to a shop to check it. It should work with both settings. Alternatively you can ask a different question here: "Why does my Canon T4i and my remote RC-6 not work with the 2-sec delay?"

Comment: You must enable the mirror lockup function. It is not on by default, and not triggered by the remote, unless you turn it on in the camera.  Look in the Custom Functions section of your manual, one is called 'Mirror Lockup".

Comment: I did enable it. In fact, it works when I shoot by pressing the button on the DSLR. The issue, is that when I press the remote, the camera shoots right away, i.e., it does not wait ~ 2 seconds and then shoot.

Answer (score 1):

The RC-1 and RC-6 infrared remotes are capable of shooting without a delay or after a 2 second delay. The RC-5 remote is only capable of shooting after a 2 second delay. If you set the RC-1 and RC-6 to 2 second delay they should all work the same way.

If the camera Drive mode is set to 2 second delay, when you press the remote button the mirror should lockup immediately, then the shutter should release after 2 seconds. If you don't feel the mirror is locking up, disable mirror lockup and see if the remote is triggering the 2 second timer. The little orange light on the front of your camera should light up to let you know the timer is counting down. If it doesn't your remote and camera are not communicating.

Comment: The mirror lockup does not work without the 2sec delay. Since all remotes support the 2sec delay, it does not matter which one you use for mirror lockup.

Comment: is this a known T4i issue? or do I need to buy a different remote?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do or at least tried and it works. I have a Canon 450D DSLR.

1. I enable mirror lock up in the camera functions.
2. Now on my 3rd party timer remote I set the delay for 10 seconds with say 1 minute exposures (I do fixed tripod astrophotography using a barn door tracker on my tripod and the camera on a ball mount attached to the barn door tracker)
3. I then set a delay of 20 seconds (to cool the camera before the next shot)
4. Then I set how many shots I want -- usually about 10 shots.

What I noticed with the remote that when I have the mirror locked up in the camera function that it seems when I click the button to start the remote to take my pictures, I only get 1 picture even though the remote will go through the program as if taking 10 pictures. Not good, plus it seems as if I don't here the mirror lock up when I press the remote to take all my pictures I programed in!

If I disable mirror lock up in the camera functions then press the remote to take my pictures, all 10 pictures are taken!! Huh I said! Again just doesn't seem the mirror goes up even though I know it does but not fast enough so I can avoid camera vibration.

So... This is what I do...I set all my parameters in my remote as stated above. I also set mirror lock up in my camera functions Now my remote ALSO has a large shutter button that can slide up to expose as long as I want...this button is important to locking the mirror up before the shutter opens via the remote telling it to. So we're all set...I press the start button on my remote. The 10 second delay will happen first, then I immediately press the large shutter button on the remote and my mirror locks up (DO NOT SLIDE IT UP JUST PRESS THE BUTTON ONCE)... The camera is still continuing the 10 second countdown I programed. After the 10 second count down ends the camera shutter opens and exposes for the time I programed (1 min) Once that 1 min is up the mirror and shutter close.

Now here is the trick...when the camera is counting the 20 second delay I programed...this gives me enough time to press large shutter button on the remote again and it then moves the mirror back up out of the way for the second shot. After the 20 second delay the shutter opens and repeats again. So in other words I have to press the shutter button once on the remote in the very beginning during the 10 second delay and once each time during my 20 second delays before each exposure starts. Presto it works and all my 10 pictures come out and I have no vibration.

I know it is a pain in the butt to have to press the shutter button once each time on the remote, but its the only way I have found to do it (mirror lock up) at least with my cheap 3rd party remote.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning uncovery's answer, I have another option with third party remotes.

Instead of pushing the button before every picture during the delays between pictures, I set my camera (Canon 50d for me) like this:
- 2 second timer shot
- mirror lockup enabled
And on my remote, I set the picture time to 2 seconds more than what I need.

That way, when the remote sends a trigger, the mirror lifts, the camera waits 2 seconds and then opens the shutter.  Then the remote closes the shutter and the delay can start and I don't have to stay there.