# Properly Using Mirror Lock With Canon EOS 60D And RC-6 IR Remote

Tags: canon, remote, mirror-lockup

I am trying to use my Canon EOS 60D on a tripod, with mirror lock enabled and shutter release via the RC-6 infrared remote, for minimizing vibration.

When using the shutter release on the camera, everything works as expected, first press locks the mirror in the "up" position, second press shoots.

But, when I try to do the same with the remote, I fail. What I try to accomplish is a pause *longer* than the 2s.

From reading [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34008/how-can-i-use-mirror-lockup-with-wireless-remote-on-a-canon-t4i) it seems I am stuck with the 2s as long as I use my RC-6.

If I use another remote (wired, for example), would that give me the desired effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wired remote will function just like the shutter button on the camera: A half press will activate metering and/or focus (depending on how your custom functions are set), the first full press will lock up the mirror. The second full press will then open the shutter to expose the image.

Just as with the shutter button on the camera, if you press once to lock up the mirror and don't press again for 30 seconds, the mirror will unlock and return to the normal position.

The ability to do a half press, the ability to activate the shutter from behind/beside the camera, and the ability to lock the remote to hold the shutter open in bulb mode is why I prefer to use my wired remote over the RC-6. It has probably been over a year since I've touched the RC-6. I use my wired remote on a near weekly basis.